# The .exe file I converted from Pyinstaller can't be run

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have made a python file and it is a pygame. I want to convert it into a .exe file.

So, I used PyInstaller
I did `pyinstaller --one file -w main.py`
and it made a .exe file.

However, when I double-click it, it popped up a

> Not Running warning

Why does it occur and what should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Which Python version do you use? What is your operating system?

Comment: @YunboSim Python 3.7.4 and Windows 7

Comment: I recommend you to try [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html). It works fine on Windows 7/8/10, Linux. Nuitka converts Python code to C then compiles to binary.